# How to use gnu plot to plot circles with vectors indicating direction?

Tags: python, vector, gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
1  1.680  24.250 0.1 0.0  1.830  24.250
2  6.330  24.860 0.1 30.0  6.460  24.935
3  9.440  24.320 0.1 60.0  9.515  24.450
4  12.110  25.790 0.1 -30.0  12.240  25.715
```

representing 4 circles with the same radius of 0.1 meters.  The format is:

```
number x y radius angle offset-x offset-y
```

The objective is to draw the 4 circles with arrows at the offset-x and offset-y at the indicated angle and have all of the arrows be the same length.  I have examined a lot of examples, but haven't been able to extract what I'm trying to do from them.

Here is my gnu plot code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset
set term pngcairo dashed font "Times,20" size 1920,1080

set loadpath "/Users/woo/.gnuplotting"
load 'default.plt'

set output 'avatars.png'

set grid
set xlabel "X" font "Times Bold,20"
set ylabel "Y" font "Times Bold,20"
set key outside right top vertical

xf(theta) = 0.1*cos(theta/180.0*pi)
yf(theta) = 0.1*sin(theta/180.0*pi)

plot "plot_file.txt" using 2:3:4 with circles, \
  "plot_file.txt" using 6:7:xf(5):yf(5)  \
   with vectors head size 0.1,20,60 filled
```

the 0.1 was to try to reduce the sizes of the vectors.  I am getting the circles, but the offsets are not the same and should be.  my offsets are at a radius of 0.15 meters supposedly.
But, all of the vectors are at growing lengths and do not point in the specified directions.

[image: Circles with vectors showing direction but not magnitude]

I have a feeling that the solution is obvious, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was the `using` part for the vectors:

```
xf(theta) = 1.0*cos(theta/180.0*pi)
yf(theta) = 1.0*sin(theta/180.0*pi)

plot "plot_file.txt" using 2:3:4 with circles,\
     "plot_file.txt" using 6:7:(xf($5)):(yf($5)) \
      with vectors head size 0.1,20,60 filled
```

With an expression, write `$5` instead of `5`. Also, the expression should be in parenthesis: `using 6:7:(xf($5)):(yf($5))` instead of `6:7:xf(5):yf(5)`.

I also changed 0.1 to 1.0 because I wanted unit vectors.

This is the result:

[image]

Every arrow is really the same length but it doesn't look that way because the x- and y-axes don't have the same scaling. To make the two axes have to same scaling, do

```
set size ratio -1
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get almost what I wanted using your great explanation.  However, notice that the lower and upper circles extend out of the plot.  How do I get their edges to show?